# Java website to Rails, reproducing password encryption

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, encryption, hash, passwords

Some time ago i wanted to play with Google Appengine and I made a java website. Now i have the need to get away from it and i would like to migrate to Rails, the website per se is not an issue but in the Java version I used [BasicPasswordEncryptor](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/util/password/BasicPasswordEncryptor.html) to encrypt my password.

Now I do not know how to get this same hashing on Ruby. The documentation says it's md5 encryption but the hashes look like

> 4+RZ+7Vn/ddlNv4rdJeeg.....

All the hashes are 32 characters long but it really doesn't look like an MD5 hash. Also i do not understand where is the salt stored.

Anyone has any info that could help figuring this out?

Thanks

Comment: You want to learn how to do this on Rails or you want to port your data to rails? these two are a bit different, so please clarify (It looks like a learning project, so it seems to lean towards the former).

Comment: I usually like to learn something but this has gone a bit above the learning level, therefore the most important thing would be to just have the data ported. I hope I explained well, thanks.

Comment: You are right. I think that the selected solution should cover you. Reason for my comment is that usually in Rails world, something like devise is used, so if you want to maintain functionality (but not current base), you should investigate that.

Comment: For future reference I add that I created this https://gist.github.com/3759053 it's very basic, but works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BasicPasswordEncryptor does following

a) It convert password to byte array
b) It create a random 8 byte salt
c) It passes 1000 times input through md5 with salt
d) It gets MD5 result - 16 bytes
e) It add to this result salt - 8 bytes
f) It base64 encode 24 bytes (MD5 and salt), which as I understand will end up being 32 bytes.

You can look at the source code here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jasypt/jasypt/1.5/org/jasypt/util/password/BasicPasswordEncryptor.java
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jasypt/jasypt/1.5/org/jasypt/digest/StandardByteDigester.java#StandardByteDigester.digest%28byte%5B%5D%29

So, you will need to have the same things done in Rails (to generate new digested passwords or check old digested passwords).

There is no way to restore original password from a digest (that's the whole point of digesting).

Comment: Thanks, this is probably what i will end up doing.